# How to Implement Excel Formula- If Negative Then 0 on an existing function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have the following goal: Select a month and calculate the 13-month sum from the specified date. I have gotten this to work with the function shared at the bottom.

However, I would like the formula to go to 0 if it's negative. I have attached an example via markdown and a picture (not sure if I am using markdown correctly).

For the example, the logic of the formula I'm looking for would start at the furthest month first.

For the first positive value, the subtraction would go to 0 as all previous numbers are negative.
i.e. -2500 + 1000 = 0

Then, you add the next "furthest" month April = 0 + 1000 = 1000

If there was a negative afterwards, say -2000, the sum would go to 0. And so on.

formula:

```
=LET(
     dates,MAP($A$5:$A$23,LAMBDA(a,EOMONTH(a,0))),
     income, $B$5:$B$23,
     lost_inventory,$C$5:$C$23,
     select_month,EOMONTH($D$2,0),
     last_month, EOMONTH(select_month,-13),
     net,income-lost_inventory,
     SUM(FILTER(net,(dates<=select_month)*(dates>=last_month))))
```

|  |  |  | Select Month | Total Income |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | Dec-23 | -500 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Date | Income | Lost Inventory |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Dec-22 |  | $ 1,000.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jan-23 |  | $ 1,000.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Feb-23 |  | $ 500.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Mar-23 | $ 1,000.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Apr-23 | $ 1,000.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| May-23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jun-23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jul-23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Aug-23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sep-23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Oct-23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Nov-23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Dec-23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jan-24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Feb-24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Mar-24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Apr-24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| May-24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jun-24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jul-24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I'm not sure whether the =MAX(0,yourformula) solution provided before would keep the order which I am looking for? Or how to add it without breaking the current function?

Comment: You should have posted one question at a time and not duplicate: **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77875109/8162520)**

Comment: So what is the end goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This wouldn't be a duplicate as there is a foundation provided here, you can see a clear difference. As for my end goal, what part of the operation or question doesn't make sense?

Comment: Doesn't mean if a foundation is provided or not.  For end goal I want to say, what should be the output, are you trying to achieve `0` when its negative ? If so then did you try the one as you have mentioned using `MAX()`? Also if using `MAX()` will there be a difference if so then what

Comment: Would the logic of the function work?

Hypothetically, if we add a column next to Lost Inventory, the process I'm looking for would be 

Dec 23' Loss 1000 + Mar 23' Profit 1000 =0 then
Jan 23' Loss 1000 =0 ... with a profit of 1000 due to April remaining. Let me know if this makes sense

Comment: That is what I am asking. I am not suggesting you to use `MAX()` it is you who has mentioned on that, I am trying to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: See comment above, sorry pressed enter too soon when trying to indent